# How to change the redirect from default language to secondary language when no lang param

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

I have a Typo3 11.5 website with the default language German (example.com/de/) and the second language English (example.com/en/).
If only the base url (example.com) is called, it is automatically redirected to the default language. I would now like to change this redirection to the secondary language.

This is my current config.yml

```yaml
base: /
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: 0
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.utf8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de
    direction: ltr
    flag: de
  -
    title: Englisch
    enabled: true
    languageId: 1
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_US.utf8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: strict
    fallbacks: ''
    flag: en-us-gb
```

By swapping the order of the languages, the correct forwarding to example.com/en works directly, but the backend language behavior is also changed so that only the English language can be edited.

I have already tried the following redirect:
`RewriteRule !^(en|de)/ https://example.de/en [R=307,L]`
However, this leads to an endless redirect.

Comment: Do it in .htaccess with a redirect.

Comment: I would also be happy with an htaccess rule that redirects all URLs without /en or /de at the beginning to https://example.de/en. I have the following rule for this:
RewriteRule !^(en|de)/ https://act.de/en [R=307,L]
However, this leads to an endless redirect in my Typo3 installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This redirect in .htaccess should do what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/en [R=301,L]
```

^$ means no path. Redirects https://example.com to https://example.com/en